# Lista simplesmente encadeada e não ordenada

Tags: c

Ao rodar o código abaixo, temos o seguinte problema, ao chamar a função `imprime_lista`, quando um elemento ja foi alocado na lista, está dando `segmentation fault`. Como resolver isso?

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

struct No{
int dado;
struct No *prox;
};
typedef struct No No;

struct lista{
struct No *inicio;
struct No *fim;
};
typedef struct lista lista;

//----------- FUNCOES ----------//

lista* cria_lista();
void insere_inicio_lista(lista *li);
void insere_fim_lista(lista *li);
void imprime_lista(lista *li);
void remover_elemento(lista *li);
void esvazia_lista(lista *li);

//---------- MAIN ----------//

int main(){
No *aux;
No *anterior;
lista *li = cria_lista();
imprime_lista(li);
insere_inicio_lista(li);
imprime_lista(li);


return 0;
}

//----------    FUNCOES     ----------//

lista* cria_lista(){
lista* li = (lista*) malloc(sizeof(lista));
if(li != NULL){
    li->fim = NULL;
    li->inicio = NULL;
}
return li;
}

void insere_inicio_lista(lista *li){
No *novo = (No*) malloc(sizeof(No));
scanf("%d", &novo->dado);
if(li->inicio == NULL){
    li->inicio = novo;
    novo->prox = NULL;
    li->fim = novo;
} else {
    novo->prox = li->inicio;
    li->inicio = novo;
}
}

void insere_fim_lista(lista *li){
No *novo = (No*)malloc(sizeof(No));
scanf("%d", &novo->dado);
if(li->inicio == NULL){
    li->inicio = novo;
    novo->prox = NULL;
    li->fim = novo;
} else {
li->fim->prox = novo;
li->fim = novo;
li->fim->prox = NULL;
}
}

void imprime_lista(lista *li){
No *aux;
No *anterior;
if(li->inicio == NULL){
    printf("Lista vazia!!\n");
} else{
    aux = li->inicio;
    do{
        printf((" %d ", aux->dado));
        aux = aux->prox;
    }while(aux != NULL);
}
}

void remover_elemento(lista *li){
No *aux;
No *anterior;
int numero;
int achou;
if(li->inicio == NULL){
    printf("Lista vazia!!\n");
} else {
    printf("Digite o numero a ser removido: ");
    scanf("%d", &numero);
    aux = li->inicio;
    anterior = NULL;
    achou = 0;
    while(aux != NULL){
        if(aux->dado == numero){
            achou++;
            if(aux == li->inicio){
                li->inicio = aux->prox;
                free(aux);
                aux = li->inicio;
            }else if (aux == li->fim){
                anterior->prox = NULL;
                li->fim = anterior;
                free(aux);
                aux == NULL;
            } else {
                anterior->prox = aux->prox;
                free(aux);
                aux = anterior->prox;
            }
        }else{
            anterior = aux;
            aux = aux->prox;
        }

    }
    if(achou == 0){
        printf("Numero nao encontrado\n");
    }else{
        printf("Numero removido %d vez(es)\n", achou);
    }
}
}

void esvazia_lista(lista *li){
No *aux;
No *anterior;
if(li->inicio = NULL){
    printf("Lista vazia!!\n");
}else{
    aux = li->inicio;
    while(aux != NULL){
        li->inicio = li->inicio->prox;
        free(aux);
        aux = li->inicio;
    }
printf("Lista esvaziada!\n");
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O principal erro que faz o seu programa falhar está no `imprime_lista` que tenta imprimir os nós não tendo a certeza que não são nulos:

```
void imprime_lista(lista *li){
    ...
    aux = li->inicio; //pode apanhar NULL se a lista estiver vazia

    do{
        printf((" %d ", aux->dado)); //não pode fazer ->dado sobre NULL
        ...
```

Sugiro que troque este laço/ciclo por um `while` normal que já resolve o problema:

```
void imprime_lista(lista *li) {
    if(li->inicio == NULL) {
        printf("Lista vazia!!\n");
    }
    else {
        No *aux = li->inicio;

        while(aux != NULL) { //while normal aqui garante que não usa o nó com NULL        
            printf(" %d ", aux->dado);
            aux = aux->prox;
        }
    }
}
```

No seu `esvazia_lista` também tem uma pequeno erro onde utiliza `=` para comparar em vez de `==`:

```
void esvazia_lista(lista *li){
    No *aux;
    No *anterior;
    if(li->inicio = NULL){
    //------------^ aqui
```

Na `remover_elemento` também tem um problema com `==` que devia ser `=`:

```
void remover_elemento(lista *li){
    ...    
    while(aux != NULL){
        if(aux->dado == numero){
            achou++;
            if(aux == li->inicio){
                ...
            }else if (aux == li->fim){
                anterior->prox = NULL;
                li->fim = anterior;
                free(aux);
                aux == NULL;
                //---^ aqui devia ser = para atribuir em vez de comparar
```

[Exemplo a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/woC2dS)

Deve sempre estar atento aos avisos que o compilador dá, pois permite-lhe apanhar estas situações rapidamente.

---

**Nota**: Não aconselho no entanto a fazer a leitura dos valores para a lista dentro das funções que adicionam, pois isso mistura a lógica dos dados com a da lista. É assim mais aconselhável ler os valores a utilizar no `main` e passa-los a essas funções.

Comment: Obrigado Isac! Foi de grande ajuda!